# Object Not Found Error Flexdashboard runtime shiny

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a top portion of a flexdashboard with runtime shiny as follows:

````
---
title: "Provider Dashboard"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)
library(scales)

source("\\clean_names.R")
source("Functions\\optimal_bin_size.R")

df_los <- readr::read_csv(
  "data\\los.csv"
  ) %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  filter(ward_cd != "EMER") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "?") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "Pathology")

df_los$dsch_date <- lubridate::mdy(df_los$dsch_date)
df_los <- as_tbl_time(df_los, index = dsch_date)

df_ra <- readr::read_csv(
  "data\\ra.csv"
) %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  filter(ward_cd != "EMER") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "?") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "Pathology")

df_ra <- rename(df_ra, pt_id = "pt_no_num")
df_ra$dsch_date <- lubridate::mdy(df_ra$dsch_date)
df_ra$adm_date  <- lubridate::mdy(df_ra$adm_date)
df_ra <- as_tbl_time(df_ra, index = dsch_date)

df_a <- df_los %>%
  dplyr::select(
    pt_id
    , dsch_date
    , los
    , performance
    , z_minus_score
    , lihn_service_line
    , hosim
    , severity_of_illness
    , pyr_group2
    , med_staff_dept
    , ward_cd
  )
df_b <- df_ra %>%
  dplyr::select(
    pt_id
    , readmit_count
    , readmit_rate_bench
    , z_minus_score
  )
df_los_ra <- dplyr::inner_join(df_a, df_b, by = "pt_id") %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = dsch_date)

```
````

I have output of df_los_ra using `glimpse(df_los_ra) and get the following:

```r
Observations: 10,147
Variables: 14
$ pt_id               [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m 14597637, 14597371, 14598064, 14596696, 14...
$ dsch_date           [3m[90m<date>[39m[23m 2018-01-01, 2018-01-01, 2018-01-01, 2018-...
$ los                 [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m 5, 6, 4, 8, 3, 1, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, ...
$ performance         [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m 3.812128, 3.968809, 4.326577, 3.737013, 6....
$ z_minus_score.x     [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m 0.1551, 0.2653, -0.0427, 0.5568, -0.4428, ...
$ lihn_service_line   [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m "GI Hemorrhage", "COPD", "CVA", "Medical",...
$ hosim               [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m "Hospitalist", "Hospitalist", "Hospitalist...
$ severity_of_illness [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, ...
$ pyr_group2          [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m "Medicaid", "Medicaid HMO", "HMO", "Medica...
$ med_staff_dept      [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m "Internal Medicine", "Internal Medicine", ...
$ ward_cd             [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m "2PED", "4SOU", "2CAD", "2NOR", "2CAD", "2...
$ readmit_count       [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...
$ readmit_rate_bench  [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m 0.1566, 0.1705, 0.0200, 0.0843, 0.2515, 0....
$ z_minus_score.y     [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m -0.4828, -0.5256, -0.0617, 2.8229, -0.7753...
```

I am then attempting to run the following:

```
gmc_los_ra <- reactive(
  {
    df_los_ra %>%
      filter(
          long filter statement, works in other document locations
        ) %>%
      #collapse_by("monthly") %>%
      dplyr::group_by(dsch_date, add = T) <-- forgotten pipe
      dplyr::summarize(
        excess_ra = round(mean(readmit_count - readmit_rate_bench), 2)
        , excess_los = round(mean(los.x - performance), 2)
      )

  }
)

renderPlot({

  print(gmc_los_ra())


})
```

Only to receive an error of `Error: object 'readmit_count' not found` yet I obviously see it being output by `glimpse` Is my syntax off?

**Session Info**

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] scales_1.0.0          tibbletime_0.1.2      forcats_0.4.0        
 [4] stringr_1.4.0         dplyr_0.8.3           purrr_0.3.2          
 [7] readr_1.3.1           tidyr_0.8.3           tibble_2.1.3         
[10] ggplot2_3.2.0         tidyverse_1.2.1       flexdashboard_0.5.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2            lubridate_1.7.4       lattice_0.20-38      
 [4] prettyunits_1.0.2     ps_1.3.0              utf8_1.1.4           
 [7] assertthat_0.2.1      zeallot_0.1.0         digest_0.6.20        
[10] R6_2.4.0              cellranger_1.1.0      backports_1.1.4      
[13] stats4_3.5.3          evaluate_0.14         httr_1.4.0           
[16] pillar_1.4.2          rlang_0.4.0           lazyeval_0.2.2       
[19] readxl_1.3.1          rstudioapi_0.10       callr_3.3.1          
[22] rmarkdown_1.14        loo_2.1.0             munsell_0.5.0        
[25] broom_0.5.2           compiler_3.5.3        modelr_0.1.4         
[28] xfun_0.8              rstan_2.19.2          pkgconfig_2.0.2      
[31] pkgbuild_1.0.3        htmltools_0.3.6       tidyselect_0.2.5     
[34] gridExtra_2.3         matrixStats_0.54.0    fansi_0.4.0          
[37] crayon_1.3.4          withr_2.1.2           grid_3.5.3           
[40] nlme_3.1-137          jsonlite_1.6          gtable_0.3.0         
[43] magrittr_1.5          StanHeaders_2.18.1-10 cli_1.1.0            
[46] stringi_1.4.3         xml2_1.2.1            generics_0.0.2       
[49] vctrs_0.2.0           tools_3.5.3           glue_1.3.1           
[52] hms_0.5.0             processx_3.4.1        parallel_3.5.3       
[55] yaml_2.2.0            inline_0.3.15         colorspace_1.4-1     
[58] rvest_0.3.4           knitr_1.23            haven_2.1.1
```

Comment: When using dplyr together with many other packages I usually add dplyr:: before each function call. Not sure that will solve your issue, but then you can be sure that it‘s not a conflicting namespace issue.

Comment: Ok so just tried that, still get the error.

Comment: @TimTeaFan its a case of a missing pipe `%>%` ...kills you everytime

Comment: Try leaving df_los_ra unchanged in the reactive without any filters like this `gmc_los_ra <- reactive({df_los_ra})` and then print `print(glimpse(gmc_los_ra()))` in your renderPlot statement.

Comment: Sometimes it just helps to post it to SO and then you'll spot the error yourself.